# Sending a zip file from Laravel to VUE js show the files and folders in it?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, jszip

I am trying to send a zip file to my VUE app using laravel API endpoint so far the laravel controller when tested on Postman returns the zip file in binary correctly:

```
public function getZipFile()
{
   try {
    $id = request('id');
    $zipURL = MarketPlace::select('zip_urls')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $url =  $zipURL->zip_urls;
    $position = strpos($url, '/storage/CodeSources/');
    $new_zip_link = substr($url, $position);
    $filePath = public_path($new_zip_link);


    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"',
        ];
        return response(file_get_contents($filePath), 200, $headers);

    } else {
        // Handle the case when the file is not found.
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Zip file not found'], 404);
    }

   } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return response()->json(['error' => $th->getMessage(), 'line' => $th->getLine()]);
}
}
```

This is the route for the method:

Route::post('/get-zip-by-id', [CodeBuilder::class, 'getZipFile']);

However I can't seem to get the file in correct format so that I can manipulate it using jszip library and I'm getting this error:

> Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html

Here is my axios method to fetch the file:

```
async getTheZipFile() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/get-zip-by-id', { id: this.id }, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        // console.log(response);
        const arrayBuffer = response.data;
        // console.log(arrayBuffer);
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        // console.log(uint8Array);
        const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(uint8Array);
        this.files = await this.extractZipContents(zip);
        // console.log(this.files);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
},
async extractZipContents(zip) {
    const files = [];
    await Promise.all(
        Object.keys(zip.files).map(async (filename) => {
            const fileData = await zip.files[filename].async('string');
            files.push({ name: filename, content: fileData });
        })
    );
    return files;
},
```

I tried changing the `responseType` to blob but didn't work.
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: "is this a zip file " - did you check whether the returned file **is** a zip file?

Comment: Yes the file is a zip but when fetching it in Vue I only get a JSON object wich is the problem

Comment: If the response is a JSON object, then it cannot be a valid zip file at the same time

Comment: @NicoHaase 
it's only valid (binary zip data) when i get the return in Postman in vue i got this :
ArrayBuffer(67)
byteLength: 67
detached: false
maxByteLength: 67
resizable: false